# What kernels were used and installed previously?

Tags: apt, kernel

(Ubuntu 20.04 if that is relevant.)

I see some hang/crash (maybe instability), which might be new due to a kernel update (I think I have not seen that with the previous kernel; I remember that there was a kernel update recently).

How can I see a log of the kernels which I had installed previously, and used previously?

(Or maybe more generic: How can I see a log of installed/updated packages, from `apt`?)

Answer (score 1):

I guess I already answered it myself during writing the question:

There is an APT log, in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

From there I see:

```
...

Start-Date: 2020-05-01  16:49:34
Requested-By: kubuntu (999)
Install: ... linux-image-5.4.0-28-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-28.32, automatic), ...
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.26.32, 5.4.0.28.33), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.26.32, 5.4.0.28.33), linux-modules-nvidia-4
40-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0-26.30+2, 5.4.0-28.32), linux-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.26.32, 5.4.0.28.33)
End-Date: 2020-05-01  16:50:23

...

Start-Date: 2020-05-05  11:24:27
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Requested-By: az (1000)
Install: linux-image-5.4.0-29-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-29.33), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-29-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-29.33), linux-headers-5.4.0-29-g
eneric:amd64 (5.4.0-29.33), linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-29-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-29.33), linux-modules-5.4.0-29-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-29.33)
, linux-headers-5.4.0-29:amd64 (5.4.0-29.33)
Upgrade: update-manager-core:amd64 (1:20.04.9, 1:20.04.10), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.28.33, 5.4.0.29.34), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4
.0-28.32, 5.4.0-29.33), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.28.33, 5.4.0.29.34), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:20.04.9, 1:20.04.10), linux-mod
ules-nvidia-440-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0-28.32, 5.4.0-29.33), linux-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.28.33, 5.4.0.29.34)
End-Date: 2020-05-05  11:25:08

...

Start-Date: 2020-05-06  09:18:30
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-26-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-26.30+2), linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-26.30)
End-Date: 2020-05-06  09:18:36

...
```

This is already helpful. (Not sure if there is anything yet better than that.)